# Adding different values ​to the entries created with the loop

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, widget, tkinter-entry

For example, I want to insert the numbers from 1 to 10, respectively, from the beginning to the end, into the 10 entries I created with a loop.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("")
root.geometry("500x400")
canva = Canvas(root,width=450,height=350,highlightbackground="black")

for i in range(40, 240, 21):
    Abent = Entry(root, width=10)
    Abentry = canva.create_window(50, i, anchor="nw", window=Abent)
    Abent.insert(0,1)

canva.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide code and context when asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#enumerate) on your `for` loop's iterable

```
for index, y_pos in enumerate(range(40, 240, 21)):  # enumerate over range
    abent = Entry(root, width=10)
    abentry = canva.create_window(50, y_pos, anchor="nw", window=abent)
    abent.insert(0, index)
```

Also: to be compliant with [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), I've renamed your variables to use lowercase names! For future reference, Uppercase Names are reserved for classes like `Entry`

Comment: Glad I could help! If this answer worked for you, please click the check mark button to mark it as "accepted" so that others know this question has been answered.